# Retrieve data from .exe-file

Tags: statistics, exe, extract

How do I communicate with a game ("Quake II"), and retrieve/extract data from it?

I have this old game (ActionQuake II) which is an mod for Quake2. 
Whenever an action has been executed within the game, it writes every transaction in a commando-prompt - just as Counter-strike. (I'm not sure, if this might be the solution...)

I suppose these transactions can be retrieved from the .EXE-files.

Is there a way to retrieve, and treat or even search in .EXE-files (in real-time)? 
I know its possible, because in some IRC-channels are bots, which write every transaction on the channel. Many homepages are doing it aswell - giving the user a server-list, with details like: Score, Deaths, Players etc. (http://www.gametracker.com), but how are they doing it?

I want to use this data for statistics and progress-overview.
Any help?

Comment: Do you want to follow the messages generated by a game in progress or do you want a static list of all the messages the game can generate?

Comment: Follow the messages the game generates. Every time a player kills three, without dying, it generates a Impressive <playername>. 3 headshots in row generates a Accuracy <playername>, and 12 kills without dying generates a Excellent <playername>. It's these commands I want to retrieve.

Comment: It would be possible if the game has an API you can use in an external program, which I'm not sure Quake and its derivative has.  Or if the game posts the messages to some external software or protocol.  It is not *from the .exe file* that you'll be able to do that.  You might have more chance asking your question on [Arcade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

If there's some kind of server, you can try sniffing the network packets with software like Wireshark.